# Using an argument from another function - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

Let's suppose I have

```
def perrin(a):
    if true:
    #Do something

def sequence(string,n)
    if string == "name":
        perrin(n)
```

I just want perrin to take the n argument from the sequence, is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: `True` needs a capital T, but otherwise, this code looks fine. Try it out and see if it works the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine you need only to edit two syntax errors:

1. Capital 'T' in `True`
2. Colon (`:`) after the function definition `def sequence(string, n)`.

The updated code looks like this

```
    def perrin(a):
        if True:
            #do something here

    def sequence(string,n):
        if string == "name":
            perrin(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

If both definitions are in the same class it looks fine to me. 
You do need to have True or False with a capital letter, else it won't regocnize is a a boolean.

Comment: Same module or file, not same class.  There's no OO here.

Comment: This could be part of code in a file, maybe the Topic starter is only showing a certain part. But you are correct.